# How to change font size of subtitles in totem movie player

Tags: fonts, totem

font size of subtitles in totem movie player is too large for me. 
how to decrease the font-size,
and can I configure the font type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Totem go to: **Edit → Preferences** and here you can set font and size.

[image]

Comment: thnx, i'vent notice tht

Comment: Any settings for subtitle font *color* ?